# Check file extension of a non string

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, module, file-extension

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os

load_list = open(askopenfilename(), "rb")
file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(load_list)
if str(file_extension).lower() == (".p", ".pickle"):
    print("pickle")
```

I've read that this method works with the file path given as a string however this does not work with my method of getting the file path.

I am receiving an error:

```
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Comment: you shouldn't incorporate things people answer/point-out about in your question via editing. That makes the answerer look bad. I have reverted your question to contain the `==` operation and added your AttributeError as needed.

Comment: @Jim Thanks, I'm new here will keep in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *comparing a string with a tuple*. You've probably meant to use `in`:

```
if file_extension.lower() in (".p", ".pickle"):
```

And, you should pass a filename to `splitext()`, not the file object. Replace:

```
file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(load_list)
```

with:

```
filename = askopenfilename()
_, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
```

Comment: OP has decided to edit-out the `==` and replace it with `in`. If you don't want to get into a rollback-edit loop just remove the first part of your answer so it doesn't look like you're pointing out something non-existent.

Comment: @Jim Sorry for the problem guys, I didn't realize I changed it back.